# How can I hide columns from a grid-view using a check-box tool on click of a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I'm creating a web project in Visual Studio 2012 using C# which fetch data from database and shows in a grid-view. There are many number of columns in the database, which shows on the grid-view as it is. I want to make an option for the user to eliminate unwanted columns using a check-box and after checking, on a button click it must update.

This is the code for my grid view.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        RunTimeDSTableAdapters.tbl_runtime_reportTableAdapter state = new RunTimeDSTableAdapters.tbl_runtime_reportTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
        DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text);
        dt = state.GetSubmitDataBy(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString(), DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString(), dt1.ToString(), dt2.ToString());
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a checkbox column in your gridview to check/uncheck the required rows.
In that case, you can achieve this on Client side only.
Write the following javascript code on your Button Click:

```
    function HideUnhideRows() {
        var myGridView = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID %>");
        var rows = myGridView.rows.length;

        for (var i = 1; i < myGridView.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = myGridView.rows[i];
            var ctrl = row.cells[0].children[0]; // if checkbox is the first column
            if (ctrl.checked) {
                row[i].style.display = "none";
            }

        }
    }
```

Button Markup:

Comment: Good, but the OP was asking about showing/hiding columns (not rows)